# Position: fixed with vertical space

Tags: css

What I have is a rather basic issue with position: fixed.

Here's a sample:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
}

.content {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="content">test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br /></div>
```

What I want is the scrolling to start **below** the black bar (with a fixed position).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add padding to second div equal to height of second div.

```
.content {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5000px;
}
```

When you say scrolling below the back bar, it sounds like you want the **content** to begin below the back bar. So add some padding to second div to account for presence of fixed div.

Comment: Well you have several solutions now. Which you pick depends on what you want. If the nav bar completely covers the top of browser window then kdtong's margin-top would seem best. If the nav bar needs to have some background effects from the content area then padding-top as I have suggested would seem best. I think these are the two most straightforward solutions.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a more flexible way of accomplishing this that doesn't require the height of the fixed div to be known (though it is less semantic).

Simply duplicate the markup for the fixed element. Set the `position` of the first of the duplicated pair to `fixed` and the `visibility` of the second to `hidden` (also make sure the `position` of the second element is unset or `relative`). Here's an example:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
}
.fixed{position:fixed}
.filler{visibility:hidden}

.content {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav fixed"></div>
<div class="nav filler"></div>
<div class="content">
  
  First<br />
  Second<br />
  Third<br />
  Fourth<br />
  Fifth<br />
  Sixth<br />
  Seventh<br />
  Eigth<br />
  Ninth<br />
  
  <br /><br /><br /><br />
  <br /><br /><br /><br />
  <br /><br /><br /><br />

  Last<br />

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/Vqncx/

I just gave the 'content' DIV relative positioning and a y-axis from the top equal to the height of the 'nav' and then gave the 'nav' a z-index to keep it on top of the 'content'.

```
.nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background: #000;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 5;
}

.content {
 background: #ccc;
 width: 100%;
 height: 5000px;
 position: relative;
 top:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a top margin to your .content div equal to the size of the .nav block + some padding:

```
.content {
    margin-top: 60px;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added an empty div above my fixed header made it invisible, with this css

```
.invisible_placeholder{
  height:80px;
}
```